# Понимание фильтров в ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я определяю метод в контроллере ROR-приложения например 'def myfilter ...' который буду использовать в качестве фильтра. Как мне прояснить для себя почему его использование объявляется как: before_filter :myfilter т. е. в виде символа а не просто before_filter myfilter ? другими словами откуда появляется именно символ :myfilter ?

Answer (score 1):

- before_filter :myfilter -- использовать метод myfilter() в качестве фильтра.
- before_filter myfilter -- использовать содержимое локальной переменной myfilter в качестве источника имени метода для фильтра.

Comment: т. е. при объявлении метода в контроллере появляется одноименный символ?

Comment: before_filter это такой метод, который принимает в качестве аргумента имя другого метода.